# How can I disable the status bar on the lock screen?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, lock-screens, htc-one-x, notification-bar

I want my lock screen to actually lock the phone.  I don't want to be able to unlock the phone and initiate a call by pulling the phone out of my pocket, or randomly select notification items if it bangs against my leg.  Is there a way to just turn all that crap off?

For anyone interested in this functionality, [I have logged a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56265).

Answer (score 2):

The only way to disable the pulldown is to not use the default swipe unlock.  Switching to a PIN, pattern, password, or face unlock will get rid of that.

Comment: That's a bit annoying, really I want the swipe unlock without anything else being swipeable.

Comment: @robertc - Yes, I know, but for some reason, the functionality to disable that feature isn't included.  I believe some custom ROMs implement such an option, but nothing stock AFAIK.